# Changing my display cable from HDMI to Display Mini lead to resolution issue mac

Tags: macos

After having a problem with the HDMI cable on Samsung Syncmaster 1600x900,
I changed it to a DisplayPort to VGA adapter, but now it is not detecting the monitor correctly.

The available resolutions for it is now 1280x1024 & 800x600.
I have shifted already to custom resolution of 1280x768 by selecting a custom resolution after pressing option and then selecting scaled displays.

But I want it to have its original resolution.

It feels like it has supposed my monitor to be secondary display.

P.S. : Already have deleted com.apple.windowserver.plist in Safe Mode.

Comment: It is telling me to get a Apple Display adapter (original), which I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now it wasn't the adapter, but the cable VGA cable which was not working out for me.

As I was suing the original Apple DisplayPort adapter.